# How can I get an objective assessment of my situation in my workplace?

Tags: work-environment, work-life-balance, germany

I have been working in a company for the past 11 months as a Web Developer. Everything was ok until two months ago when I experienced some personal problems which were reflected in my quality of work, and I am feeling about 75% sure that they want to fire me. They already hired someone else who'll start in one month, and I got a lot of bad remarks from them, such as that it could be hard to continue with me.

The problem is that when I try to talk to the project manager, or to the leader, or anyone else, no one gives me a clear answer. They seem like they are just trying to avoid to answer, or they say that for the past couple months I haven't been like I was at first. I ask what will happen to me, and all they'll say is that everything will be ok.

My question is how to get useful information about my situation? Especially because I am getting a lot of other offers and I don't want to lose them.

**Notes**:

- I am working in Germany.
- I have a family and I need the work.
- I enjoy the work and I like the environment and all co-workers.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you are projecting your fear of losing job onto their behaviour. The fact that they hired someone else or are going to hire him by itself doesn't mean anything and could have multiple valid explanations.
Second of all could you describe in more detail what do you mean by

> no one gives me a clear answer

What have you asked them exactly? How exactly did they reply? If they are telling you that you are not getting replaced then either they mean it and you have nothing to worry about or they are unwilling to tell you the truth in which case I'm afraid there is not much you can do to make them admit that.

One thing that you could do regarding the job offers you are getting is, if you are still strongly convinced that they are dishonest you might just change the job yourself. You won't have to worry about missing the good job opportunities.

Comment: What I asked, is what is my current situation? will I be fired? Will they keep me? Should I start to look about another job? and what I got as answer, is that the time will show everything..

Answer (score 1):

They will not tell you: "Hey, yeah, we want to fire you as soon as this new guy joins the company". 
If you want answers, you should talk about future projects, your role and that. If the answers doesn't make you feel better and you keep thinking they might want to fire you, you should

1. Start looking for another job. Update your resume, your portfolio and Linkedin profile
2. Think about what could have happened so they suddenly decided to fire you. What can you improve about yourself and your job? You can ask for feedback from your manager and peers.